# Can I End Bartlett Suckers with weed fabric

Tags: suckers

I have the same sucker problem and consequently do NOT have ab acceptable lawn. My thoughts are to: remove all suckers, lay down 2 layers of weed fabric, an inch or so of crushed stone, then 8 inches of top soil and then sod over it all.

Does anyone think this will work ??

Comment: Same sucker problem as who else? Weed fabric prevents weeds from above germinating below, not suckers. Stone, soil, and sod will do nothing.

Comment: Are you trying to kill your tree? Eight inches of top soil on top of tree roots WILL kill the tree over time. Fabric will kill your soil fairly quickly, too.

Answer (score 2):

If you have "sucker problems" leading to "not having an acceptable lawn" you have inadequate non-lawn space around the pear tree.

Rootstock suckers a a common maintenance issue with grafted pears, and are best dealt with by ripping them out as they appear. That will have no impact on your lawn if you have an adequate sized ring of mulched ground (no grass)  around the tree.

Either that, or cut down the tree and remove the roots. Whether you are digging out 8-10 inches and refilling with fabric, gravel, dirt and sod, or adding 8-10 inches of fabric, gravel, dirt and sod, you'll probably kill the tree slowly that way.

Answer (score 1):

Once I too, shared your enthusiasm for weed fabric, even going so far as to buy the superior grade material called geotextile which is a stronger woven version.

In some sections of my garden I have had weed fabric down for over ten years. The most successful locations are in north facing or low light areas so when weeds start growing it is at a slower pace.

Fabric or even pool liner, which is totally impervious to roots, did not stop horsetails  (equisetum), Common milkweed (Asclepias) or even creeping bellflower (Campanula).  They grow under or around it and pop up where the fabric ends even if that is many feet away from the source. I doubt it will stop the roots of an established tree.  You will just move the location of the problem

Some other things to note:

- eight inches of soil may seem like enough but additional watering may be needed in dry spells
- not sure why you would want to add crushed stone as this will not add anything to the solution
- in the long run the soil under the fabric can become compacted

[This site](https://www.gardenmyths.com/landscape-fabric-weed-barrier-cloth/) has some interesting commentary on the use of fabric but one line echoes my own experience

> "a 6- 12 inch layer of wood chip mulch is just as effective"